# How can I calculate variable in constructor using another variable in this constructor function

Tags: javascript, oop

```
class CreateNewWord {
  constructor(id, title, hold, droppedHere, bg) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title; <=== I want to use this variable
    this.hold = hold;
    this.droppedHere = droppedHere;
    this.bg = bg;
    this.letters = getLetter(title); <=== I want to make something like this
  }

function getLetter(word) {
  let letters = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    letters.push({
      id: i + 1,
      title: word[i],
      hold: false,
      droppedHere: false,
      bg: "#a29bfe",
    });
  }
  return letters;
}

}
```

So when I want to create an object I don't have to pass letters since it is created inside of the class

SOLUTION:

From

```
function  getLetter(word) {...
```

To

```
getLetter(word) {... since I get and error if I use "function get..."
```

AND wrote this:

```
this.letters = this.getLetter(title);
```

thanks "ponury-kostek" for the help!

Comment: Just change `this.letters = letters(title);` to `this.letters = this.getLetter(title);`

Comment: Just move the `function` declaration outside of your `class` (since `getLetter` doesn't have anything to do with instance objects) and it'll work.